# Which RESTful HTTP verb to use for reading time-varying state?

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

I'm contemplating creating a RESTful API to monitor a remote instrument - for purposes of discussion, assume the remote instrument is a voltmeter.

One important function of the API is to read the voltage as measured by the instrument at any time.

My question: what, if any, is the appropriate HTTP verb for reading a value that can change from one reading to the next?

As I understand it, GET would be wrong, since servers may assume the value is idempotent and thus cache the returned value.

But the other usual choices -- PUT and POST -- appear to be used to create and update values and not return values.

I can think of a few approaches:

- Use GET with a Cache-Control: no-cache in the header
- Use (or abuse) POST and have it return a value
- Don't use RESTful design for this kind of application

What is considered the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question: what, if any, is the appropriate HTTP verb for reading a value that can change from one reading to the next?

[GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1)

> The GET method requests transfer of a current selected representation for the target resource.

The semantics of caching are described in [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234); in particular, you can use the [Cache-Control header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) to provide to intermediary components the metadata they need to cache the responses correctly.  The list of cache control directives includes [no-cache](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.4), if you always want the intermediary components to check with the origin before reusing a value.

This is the main point of the [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) - because resources uniformly implement a consistent set of semantics, clients and intermediaries can rely upon those semantics to contribute *without needing to know the specific details* of the resource, it's implementation, or it's representation.

> The central feature that distinguishes the REST architectural style from other network-based styles is its emphasis on a uniform interface between components (Figure 5-6). By applying the software engineering principle of generality to the component interface, the overall system architecture is simplified and the visibility of interactions is improved. Implementations are decoupled from the services they provide, which encourages independent evolvability. The trade-off, though, is that a uniform interface degrades efficiency, since information is transferred in a standardized form rather than one which is specific to an application's needs. The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Use GET as thats implicit meaning when you want to only fetch some data from a server.

As you said correctly you need to have right cache mechanism (i said it purposefully as you may just set cache max age 0 but you might also need cache at any later point) implimented to make sure you get fresh data in the response.